# jQuery - Apply styling to all vertical TD in table on hover

Tags: jquery, css, indexing, html-table

If you hover over a price, you will notice the price and 1st child of .catTr td is highlighted. None of the others are. The goal is to create a very clear grid of what is being selected.

**How can I get it to apply the same styling to every child td in the column with class tr.cat ?**

Live Link: http://www.sinsysonline.com/cameron/nick/repair/price.html

HTML:

```
<table id="prices">
    <tr>
        <td class="clear"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="head">
        <td class="clear"></td>
        <td class="head">
            <a href="desktop.html"><h3>Desktop</h3></a>
        </td>
        <td class="head">
            <a href="laptop.html"><h3>Laptop</h3></a>
        </td>
        <td class="head">
            <a href="server.html"><h3>Server</h3></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="priceRow">
        <td class="clear"></td>
        <td class="price">
            <h2>Testing</h2>
        </td>
        <td class="price">
            <h2>Testing</h2>
        </td>
        <td class="price">
            <h2>Testing</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="catTr">
        <td class="category">
            <a href="services_hwrep.html">Hardware Repair</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="catTr">
        <td class="category">
            <a href="services_netts.html">Network Troubleshooting</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="catTr">
        <td class="category">
            <a href="services_netts.html">Network Troubleshooting</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="catTr">
        <td class="category">
            <a href="services_netts.html">Network Troubleshooting</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="catTr">
        <td class="category">
            <a href="services_netts.html">Network Troubleshooting</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="foot">
        <td div class="clear"></td>
        <td class="foot">
                <a href="contact.html" class="action_button">Contact Us</a>
        </td>
        <td class="foot">
                <a href="contact.html" class="action_button">Contact Us</a>
        </td>
        <td class="foot">
                <a href="contact.html" class="action_button">Contact Us</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
(function() { 

    $('tr.catTr td').not('.category').hover(function(){

        var priceSel = $(this).index();

        $('tr#priceRow td').eq(priceSel).addClass('price_hover');
        $('tr.catTr td').eq(priceSel).addClass('vertFilt');

        $(this).closest('tr').find('td.category').addClass('category_hover');

    },function(){

        var priceSel = $(this).index();

        $('tr#priceRow td').eq(priceSel).removeClass('price_hover');
        $('tr.catTr td').eq(priceSel).removeClass('vertFilt');

        $(this).closest('tr').find('td.category').removeClass('category_hover');

    });

})();
</script>
```

Live Link:
http://www.sinsysonline.com/cameron/nick/repair/price.html

**Now, how to highlight EVERY equivalent child in the column....**

I know I need to do something with .each(), but I'm unsure where to put it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly this is what you are looking for:

To addClass:

```
$('tr.catTr td:nth-child(' + (priceSel+ 1) + ')').addClass('vertFilt');
```

To RemoveClass:

```
$('td.vertFilt').removeClass('vertFilt');
```

#### JS

```
  $('tr.catTr td').not('.category').hover(function () {
       var priceSel = $(this).index();
       $('tr#priceRow td').eq(priceSel).addClass('price_hover');
       $('tr.catTr td:nth-child(' + (priceSel + 1) + ')').addClass('vertFilt');
       $(this).closest('tr').find('td.category').addClass('category_hover');

   }, function () {
       var priceSel = $(this).index();
       $('tr#priceRow td').eq(priceSel).removeClass('price_hover');
       $('td.vertFilt').removeClass('vertFilt');
       $(this).closest('tr').find('td.category').removeClass('category_hover');
   });
```

Comment: Wow, that worked perfect... then I fubar'd it up.
Let me figure out what I messed up :-P

Comment: Infact i just ran it in the chrome console and seems to work fine.. :)

Comment: Well, I saw it working and I personally broke it. I guess this is my responsibility :-P

Comment: *bold* HEAVILY MODIFED *bold*

The answer was to use:
$('tr.catTr td:nth-child(' + (priceSel+ 1) + ')').addClass('vertFilt');

Answer (score 0):

To add a class for an entire column use `td:nth-child(n)` where `n` is the column number.  In your case, the columns you want to highlight vary from 2-4.  You also need to prevent the head, foot, etc. elements from being highlighted, so use `.not()`.

```
$('table#prices tbody td:nth-child(3)')
  .not('.head,.price,.foot,.category_hover')
  .addClass('vertFilt');
```

So, for your situation, try this:

```
$('tr.catTr td').not('.category').hover(function(){

    var priceSel = $(this).index();

    $('table#prices tbody td:nth-child('+priceSel+')')
      .not('.head,.price,.foot,.category_hover')
      .addClass('vertFilt');

    ...

},function(){

    var priceSel = $(this).index();

    $('table#prices tbody td:nth-child('+priceSel+')')
      .not('.head,.price,.foot,.category_hover')
      .removeClass('vertFilt');

    ...
```

Comment: I like the idea, and I know I could make that work, but looking for a jQuery solution

Comment: This is 100% jQuery. The $ is shorthand for the jQuery object.